# How to aggregate test results in jenkins parallel pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a `Jenkinsfile` with a definition for parallel test execution, and the task is to grab the test results from both in order to process them in a `post` step somewhere.

Problem is: How to do this? Searching for anything acting as an example code does not bring up anything - either the examples deal with explaining `parallel`, or they explain `post` with `junit`.

```
pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'swarm' } }

    stages {
        stage('Testing') {
            parallel {
                stage('Unittest') {
                    agent { node { label 'swarm' } }

                    steps {
                        sh 'unittest.sh'
                    }
                }

                stage ('Integrationtest') {
                    agent { node { label 'swarm' } }

                    steps {
                        sh 'integrationtest.sh'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Defining a `post {always{junit(...)}}` step at both parallel stages yielded a positive reaction from the BlueOcean GUI, but the test report recorded close to double the amount of tests - very odd, some file must have been scanned twice. Adding this `post` step to the surrounding "Testing" stage gave an error.

I am missing an example detailing how to post-process test results that get created in a `parallel` block.

Answer (score 11):

Just to record my solution for the internet:

I came up with stashing the test results in both parallel steps, and adding a final step that unstashes the files, then `post`-processes them:

```
pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'swarm' } }

    stages {
        stage('Testing') {
            parallel {
                stage('Unittest') {
                    agent { node { label 'swarm' } }

                    steps {
                        sh 'rm build/*'
                        sh 'unittest.sh'
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            stash includes: 'build/**', name: 'testresult-unittest'
                        }
                    }

                }

                stage ('Integrationtest') {
                    agent { node { label 'swarm' } }

                    steps {
                        sh 'rm build/*'
                        sh 'integrationtest.sh'
                    }

                    post {
                        always {
                            stash includes: 'build/**', name: 'testresult-integrationtest'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Reporting') {
            steps {
                unstash 'testresult-unittest'
                unstash 'testresult-integrationtest'
            }

            post {
                always {
                    junit 'build/*.xml'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My observation though is that you have to pay attention to clean up your workspace: Both test stages do create one file, but on the second run, both workspaces are inherited from the previous run and have both previously created test results present in the `build` directory.

So you have to remove any remains of test results before you start a new run, otherwise you'd stash an old version of the test result from the "other" stage. I don't know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: That odd feeling when you google your problem and find your own question without a satisfying enough answer... My current problem remains unsolved: How to trigger the final reporting step if one of the test steps fails. By default the execution stops after the parallel step if something fails.

Comment: I solved that by making sure the test steps never fails. I caught the return status of the sh step and if a non-zero value I manually set currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'

Comment: I think you can add a `post { always { /* reporting step here */ } } ` directly inside the `parallel` block since you're using the declarative pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure the *stage('Reporting')* will be always executed, put all the step in the 'post':

```
post {
    always {
        unstash 'testresult-unittest'
        unstash 'testresult-integrationtest'
        junit 'build/*.xml'
    }
}
```